# Cannot access macOS Server from the other mac using wifi

Tags: xcode, osx-server, xcode-server

This is how it is managed in macOS Server:

[image]

and then from the other mac I do:

[image]

but it doesn't work, cannot login to remote mac. Why?

- User **kuna** exists on mac with macOS Server and is an admin.

Comment: Are you forwarding all the necessary ports?

Comment: What do you mean? What ports?

Comment: If the server is in an office or residential location, there would typically be a router managing Internet traffic, and that router would have to do port forwarding for any external requests to be forwarded to the server. Is that the case, or does the server have its very own IP?

Comment: Yes, server is in an office.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to access your server from *inside* the office, don’t use the public IP - use the server’s local IP (one of the ones starting `192.168....`)

If you want to access your server from *outside* the office, you may have to configure your office router to forward the relevant traffic to your server. This process is called [port forwarding.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding)

I’d

- find out the port numbers you need to forward on [this page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202944)
- Google `<name of your router> setup port forwarding` for how to enter them into your router - although with many routers, the process is pretty self-explanatory in the admin interface.

Comment: Even after port forwarding there seems to be an issue that I have not found a solution to with SSL certificates. In Xcode 9, turning on Xcode Server automatically generates a self signed SSL certificate that is rejected over a remote connection. If anyone knows of a solution to this I would love to know. I have a professionally signed certificate stored in macOS Server but it fails to use it.